# How to programmatically determine typing mode for Voiceover?

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

With Voiceover turned on, you can move the rotor to the "Typing mode" setting; up and down swiping then lets you switch between "Standard typing" and "Touch typing". Standard typing requires you to tap once to select a key and then double-tap to actually type that letter; touch typing allows you to move your finger around the keyboard, and when you lift off a key that letter is typed (allowing you to type much faster).

I'm tasked with enabling this type of keyboard behavior on a custom keyboard that we've implemented in our application. To do this **I need to know whether the user has standard or touch typing turned on**.

Comment: Does it help if you set the keyboard key trait (`UIAccessibilityTraitKeyboardKey`) on the custom keys?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: wow, it sure seems like that's what I'm looking for. Let me try it out - you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can use the keyboard key trait (`UIAccessibilityTraitKeyboardKey`) on your custom keys to get that behaviour. From docs:

> The accessibility element behaves as a keyboard key.

I haven't tried it myself but as far as I know it should change the behaviour of that accessibility element to the typing mode that the user has selected in the rotor, much like the the "allows direct interaction" trait changes how accessibility elements behave.

Comment: Is it required to use UIButton with UIAccessibilityTraitKeyboardKey trait or it can be any UIResponder subclass?